# Get values for a reference where a key exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ref    key        val
--------------------------
1      Include    Yes
1      Color      Green
1      Shape      Square
2      Include    No
2      Color      Red
2      Shape      Circle
```

If an `Include` key exists with value `Yes`, I'd like to get all the values with the same ref.

So for the above example the result should be:

```
ref    key        val
--------------------------
1      Include    Yes
1      Color      Green
1      Shape      Square
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select *
from ref_table
where ref in
(
  select ref
  from ref_table
  where key = 'Include' and val = 'Yes'
)
```

This also seems to work:

```
with included
as
(
  select ref
  from ref_table
  where key = 'Include' and val = 'Yes'
)

select *
from ref_table
where ref in
(
  select * from included
)
```

Just wondering if there is a better (simpler) way to do this.

Comment: I would use `exists` but both methods are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM ref_table t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ref_table s
             WHERE t.ref = s.ref and s.key = 'Include' and s.val = 'Yes')
```

I always prefer this method over `IN()` , most of the time it performs better (exists wait for the first record to return) , it is also more clear for that purpose. `IN()` can also have problems when it can return `NULL` values.

Another way is an `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM ref_table t
INNER JOIN ref_table s
 ON(t.ref = s.ref and s.key = 'Include' and s.val = 'Yes')
```

Comment: That was just a typo when I created the question. Both queries work, just wondering if this is really the way to do it or if there is a better way.

Comment: Yea, I saw that, fixed. @Aetherix

Answer (score 0):

One more way with OUTER APPLY, but I guess it is not much simpler:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM ref_table r
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT ref 
    FROM ref_table 
    WHERE [key] = 'Include' and val = 'Yes') p
WHERE p.ref = r.ref
```